# Rescatar valor por JavaScript MVC C#

Tags: javascript, html, c#, mvc

Quiero rescatar el valor del `id` que esta en el cuadro rojo y llevarlo a una variable de JavaScript(Flecha roja) ¿De que manera se puede hacer?

PD: el `id` se encuentra dentro de una tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre. de paso, que tienen que ver las etiquetas c#, mvc o html?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [`@Html.HiddenFor`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.hiddenfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_InputExtensions_HiddenFor__2_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___), si estas usando mvc con añadirlo a un modelo es suficiente:

`@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)`

y lo recuperas desde jquery con:

`$('#Id').val()`

Si no lo quieres en un modelo con alojarlo en una variable y asignarlo, también te serviria:

```
@{
   int tuVariable = elvalor;
}

@Html.HiddenFor(tuVariable, new { @id = "Id" });
```